# How to make a multilingual script work in a shopping cart

Tags: javascript, webflow

I’m developing an ecommerce website and I’m looking to make a multi language experience. I duplicated almost all pages except product page and checkout page.

[This tutorial](https://discourse.webflow.com/t/tutorial-full-multi-language-site-easy-to-set-up-and-to-use/67398/101) works perfectly except for the cart. As you can see, the text doesn’t change according to the language and stay like that : [[fr]] xxxx [[en]] xxx
Does someone have an idea to solve my issue?

https://preview.webflow.com/preview/ikinesis-test?utm_medium=preview_link&utm_source=designer&utm_content=ikinesis-test&preview=142bb9a901b87c8b6cf91e26da18a063&pageId=6266e55a7a346139817247c6&workflow=preview

Thank you !!

Here the code implemented :

In the header :

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {
    var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
    for(var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
        var anchor = anchors[i];
        anchor.onclick = function() {
            code = this.getAttribute('whenClick');
            eval(code);   
        }
    }
}
```

Before the /body tag :

```
var DEAFULT_LANG = "fr";
var LANG_REG_EXP = /\[\[([a-z]{2})\]\]([^\[]+)/g;
var isStorageEnabled = ! (typeof localStorage == 'undefined');
var user_lang = (navigator.userLanguage||navigator.browserLanguage||navigator.language||DEAFULT_LANG).substr(0,2);

var getLangParam = function(){
    var arr = /lang=([a-z]{2})/g.exec(location.search);
    return arr ? arr[1] : null;
}

var getLangFromStorage = function(){
    return isStorageEnabled ? localStorage.getItem('lang') : undefined;
}

var setLang = function(lang){
    user_lang = lang;
    if(isStorageEnabled){
        localStorage.setItem('lang', user_lang);
    }
    applyLang();
}

var applyLang = function(){
    globalDict.forEach(function(v){
        $(v.elm).html(v.dict[user_lang]);
    });
}

function textNodesUnder(el){
  var n, a=[], walk=document.createTreeWalker(el,NodeFilter.SHOW_ALL,null,false);
  while(n=walk.nextNode()){
      a.push(n);
  }
  return a;
}

var globalDict = [];

$(function(){
    
    user_lang = getLangParam() || getLangFromStorage() || user_lang;

    if(isStorageEnabled){
        localStorage.setItem('lang', user_lang);
    }

    // bugfix for IE11
    // if multilingual sentence is divided into sevaral text node, restore original text node
    $("*").each(function(i,v){
        if(LANG_REG_EXP.test($(this).text().replace(/\n/g,"")) && $(this).html().indexOf("<") == -1){
            $(this).text($(this).text().replace(/\n/g,""));
        }
        var $v = $("#" + $(this).attr("id"));
        if($v.length > 0 && LANG_REG_EXP.test($v.text().replace(/\n/g,"")) && $v.html().indexOf("<") == -1){
            $v.text($v.text().replace(/\n/g,""));
        }
    })
    
    textNodesUnder(document).filter(function(v){
        return LANG_REG_EXP.test(v.nodeValue);
    }).forEach(function(v,i){
        var dict = {};
        var arr;
        while((arr = LANG_REG_EXP.exec(v.nodeValue)) != null){
            dict[arr[1]] = arr[2];
        }
        globalDict.push({elm:$(v).parent()[0], dict:dict});        
    });
    applyLang();
});
</script>

<!-- Language: French -->
<script>
    $(".french *:not(ul)").html(function(i,v) {
    return "[[fr]]" + v + "[[en]]  <b></b>";});
</script>

<!-- Language: English -->
<script>
    $(".english *:not(ul)").html(function(i,v) {
    return "[[en]]" + v + "[[fr]]  <b></b>";});
</script>

<style>
   ul{
    list-style:none;
   }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your preview link is not working, but I know you are trying to use the solution posted on Webflow's forum.

I would recommend you to try using this one, which is a fork from the original one and a lot more well developed:

https://github.com/dfdgsdfg/webflow-multilingual

The usage and configs are the same, so you probably do not have to change your implementation all over again.